# How to make static PSD fit into Responsive Bootstrap grids

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, photoshop

If you have a designer that is not specifically designing a PSD(mockup) around bootstrap column sizes how do you make the two fit ? It seems to me the options are :
1. Generate a Custom bootstrap grid
2. Don't use bootstrap
3. Use a mix of bootstrap and fixed width columns (Yuck? )

I'm sure I'm not the only one who has ever faced this problem . Looking for real world solutions or documentation. Not theories. 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a psd file, the problem that you can encounter is the width of the blocks. The height don't causes problems, but the width ussually do because mabey the psd is not made to work with 12 colums like bootstrap does, but the solution for this case is the `nested grid`. You keep nesting the elements until you get the right width of your blocks. I didn't recived yet any psd that i could not build it with bootstrap.