# How to use bootstrap grid for psd not specifically made for bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My question is similar to this: [How to make static PSD fit into Responsive Bootstrap grids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767022/how-to-make-static-psd-fit-into-responsive-bootstrap-grids/26767135)

But the selected answer (nested grid) confused me. (I can't post comments yet and I thought maybe other people would have more suggestions as well.)

Suppose I am given a psd design of 896 px with menu on left side taking about 213 px and some spacing of 10 px and then other stuff taking 683 px. How would I use bootstrap grid for something like that? I don't want any fixed-width columns. Please elaborate on the nested grid approach (or any other approach you may have).

[image]
See the picture: A is 213px, B is 896px and the spacing in between is 10px.

Comment: could you provide even a basic picture of what the design looks like?

Comment: My other comment would be, do you have to stick to the pixel widths given to you or can you expand upon them as long as the design looks correct? Bootstrap uses a container size of 1200px.

Comment: @ben.kaminski See the edited question. Please make suggestions for both cases, if possible: 1)I can expand upon the pixel widths 2)I have to stick to the ones given.

Comment: where does the "other stuff" come into play. The 683px?  What you have in your image is pretty easy, no real nesting necessary.

Comment: @ben.kaminski Yes, the other stuff is B - 683px.

Comment: ah... I see, the total page width would be 896px.

Comment: @ben.kaminski so how do I lay it out in bootstrap?

Comment: sorry it took so long... refresh the page, I added an answer and some fiddles.

Comment: @paulalexandru If you see this question, please do post an answer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1: (What I would do)
I would conform to Bootstrap's grid system as is with the 1200px main container that you should be using. Doing this gives you 2 desktop views (small and large) as well as a tablet and mobile view for the layout your looking to do.

This is what it would look like... bare bones minimum:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <p>Sidebar</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
         <p>Main Content</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/hrzboLex/

Scenario 2:
Using the 896px maximum width will limit the amount of different viewports you will see but it still will remain responsive.  What I did here was override the width of the container to 896px and kept all the same html/css.

```
.container {
 width: 896px;
 border: 1px solid;    
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/b9Lyfzxd/

Both seem to work.  If you notice the lonely "div class="col-sm-1" (in the html) that's providing you with the gap you're looking for. There are may ways you can take this further depending on your ability to manipulate CSS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm really confused how this works or maybe I simply don't understand bootstrap grid. This is my confusion: Grid has 12 columns. If A was 224 px, then I would simply make it col-md-3 (896/12*3 =224). However, neither A or B given in my question come out easily like that. Do you see my source of confusion?

Comment: I see your confusion indeed.  What confuses me is why your limiting yourself by using fixed widths in a responsive web? The only other real option would be to download a custom BS build at: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed width"? Even if we look at Scenario 1, how do I solve my confusion?

Comment: You should really visit: http://getbootstrap.com and familiarize yourself with the entire library. I don't think you're quite grasping the grid system. Or maybe it's a css thing? According to your drawing I replicated your design in Bootstrap. That's about all I can do for you. Sorry bud.

Comment: I know CSS pretty well. I just can't wrap my head around what to do when A or B is not some nice number like 224px (for a 896px design) or 300px (for a 1200px design). Because then I don't know how to utilize 12-column grid system. Thanks for your help so far.